# Self Documenting APIs built on Django-Tastypie

Tags: django, api, documentation, tastypie

Im using django-tastypie and I'm very happy with it. But I really want to get the self documenting api feature from Django Rest Framework.

What solutions exist (or have people built) to get this kind of auto generated documentation that Django Rest Framework, but from a TastyPie based API ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to use it myself but django-tastypie-swagger looks promising (https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger/). Swagger itself is a great choice for API documentation (https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/).